# SAVING XML OUTPUT

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml output using php and now i want to save this output as .xml to my file, how do i do that? please help me.

```html
<xml>
<data>
<value>abcd</value>
<color>000000</color>
<border>thin</border>
<fontstyle>11double</fontstyle>
<fontsize>22</fontsize>
<fontname>Adobe Fangsong Std R</fontname>
<fontcolor>000000</fontcolor>
<alignment>general</alignment>
</data>
<data>
<value>efgh</value>
<color>000000</color>
<border>thin</border>
<fontstyle>double</fontstyle>
<fontsize>11</fontsize>
<fontname>Calibri</fontname>
<fontcolor>000000</fontcolor>
<alignment>general</alignment>
</data>
</xml>
```

Comment: @AlokPatel hello sir! :) it was a data from EXCEL that i converted into xml using PHP and now i wanted to save that XML output. Still trying to look for an answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `file_put_contents()`. You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Alternatively, you may use the PHP file functions (`fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`).

[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

[fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

[fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)